# Issue in automating table data filling in firefox using webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**Objective:**

This is data driven approach. I am trying to get data from sheet to be entered in table in a web application. Now in the table there are fields as below:

> Textfield (To enter name), Datatype drop-down (To select data type), Length field(to enter the length), Status field (Isactive or not)

Now here there is a dynamic logic as for only “String” datatype the “Length” field would appear else in default table “Length” field/column is not shown because for other data types there is static length value provided.

Now when automating I am getting data in sequence from sheet and setting that in table. Switching over the fields is done by using “Tab” mechanism.

**Issue:**

The only issue in this whole process is that while selecting “String” data-type from drop-down and after that tab is applied. At this point the “Length” field is supposed to appear for which data can be entered from the sheet but here at only tabbing/loosing focus from one field to another is not revealing the hidden “Length” field.

And at this point automation gets stuck up. Manually selecting the drop-down shows the “Length” field but when same is done manually using tab, the “Length” field does not show up.

It would be of really great help if anyone can please suggest on above issue.
Hoping to hear soon from someone. Thanks for your efforts in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Manually selecting the drop-down shows the “Length” field but when
>   same is done manually using tab, the “Length” field does not show up.

Seems selenium isn't setting focus to the same object/element that you are. How are you using selenium to tab between fields? Do you have to tab to this element, or can you have selenium select it directly? Also, it would help us if you shared the selenium code and html.